# First-letter capitalization fails when touching ampersand

Tags: php

I have the following PHP function which works well in almost all cases:

```
function NormalizeWords($str, $disallowAllUppercase = false){
    $parts = explode(' ', $str);

    if($disallowAllUppercase){
        $result = array_map(function($x){
            return ucwords(strtolower($x));
        }, $parts);
    }else{
        $result = array_map(function($x){
            if (!ctype_upper($x)) {
                return ucwords(strtolower($x));
            }
            return $x;
        }, $parts);
    }
    
    return implode(' ', $result);
}
```

But here's a case where it misses the mark:

```
$testinput = "M&S ACME BUSINESS";
$testoutput = NormalizeWords($testinput);
die($testoutput);

Expected result: M&S ACME BUSINESS
Actual result: M&s ACME BUSINESS
```

The `s` goes to lowercase.

As you can see, `$disallowAllUppercase` remains false, so any upper-case characters should be left alone.

Here are a few examples of expected results:

```
"THIS IS MY BUSINESS NAME" ($disallowAllUppercase is true) - should be: "This Is My Business Name"
"THIS IS MY BUSINESS NAME" ($disallowAllUppercase is false) - should be: "THIS IS MY BUSINESS NAME"
"aNotheR BUSINESS nAME" ($disallowAllUppercase is true) - should be: "Another Business Name"
"aNotheR BUSINESS nAME" ($disallowAllUppercase is false) - should be: "Another BUSINESS Name"
```

How can I change my function to achieve that result?

Comment: `"aNotheR BUSINESS nAME" ($disallowAllUppercase is false)` - should actually be: `ANotheR BUSINESS NAME` since `$disallowAllUppercase remains false, so any upper-case characters should be left alone.` ?

Comment: The problem is with `ctype_upper`. It is returning `FALSE` for `M&S` (as it should) and you are then lower-casing it, and finally upper-casing the first letter. One option is to strip out all non-A-Z characters before using `ctype_upper`.

Comment: The other option as user2476294 pointed out in their comment, is to manually compare the string using `strtoupper($str) !== $str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to play a little and i made this

```
function normalize($str, $disallowAllUppercase = false) {
    $arr = array_map(function ($w) use ($disallowAllUppercase) {
        return ucfirst((strtoupper($w) !== $w || $disallowAllUppercase) ? strtolower($w) : $w);
    }, explode(" ", $str));
    return implode(" ", $arr);
}
```

You can try it on phpsandbox i made dumps on it
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ee712a7780bab56e94e3046f2dd9b87c2e99eae

Does it answer to your need ?

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

As described in the documentation for `ucwords` you can use the second parameter:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

> The optional delimiters contains the word separator characters.

You can define the ampersand as an additional delimiter. Note that you should pass the default values (linebreak, space etc.) as well:

```
return ucwords(strtolower($x), " \t\r\n\f\v&");
```

Comment: Seems promising, but doesn't take into account $disallowAllUppercase being true.

Comment: Since only alphabetical chars can be lower or uppercase and this is already implemented with strtoupper, can't you just replace the ctype_upper method with the following check: `strtoupper($str) == $str`? This should solve the problem since ctype_upper is false with the ampersand although you want it to be true I think?